# SPSS Syntax to add up values for all variables with the same prefix

Tags: syntax, macros, spss

I am wondering if there is a way to have SPSS add up all variables that have the same prefix. For example, I have variables named `MFQAP.1`, `MFQAP.2`, `MFQAP.3`, etc. Is there a way to tell SPSS to add up all variables that begin with `MFQAP.`? I know I can tell SPSS to add up all variables from `MFQAP.1` to `MFQAP.n` (where `n` is the highest number in the dataset). However, I am working with a dataset that will be continually updated, and the highest value for `n` may change. I do not want to have to always update my syntax. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to create a macro containing a comma separated list of the relevant variables:

```
spssinc select variables macroname="!MyVars"  
  /properties pattern="MFQAP.*"/options separator=", ".
```

You can now use the macro to calculate the sum like this:

```
compute MFQAPsum=sum(!MyVars).
```