# Looping through multiple string variables to generate outcome variable of presence/absence

Tags: string, loops, syntax, macros, spss

I have a very large dataset of multiple diagnoses (25) per patient represented by ICD 10 codes in SPSS. For brevity sake I have posted a snapshot of what I am attempting to replicate simply using a test dataset of 3 string variables labeled DIAG1 to DIAG3 and random codes.

[image]

Assume each row represents a patient.  The outcome presented in column "O74" is what I am attempting to replicate, but with no avail thus far (have simply manually entered what I wish to replicate with syntax).  Essentially a presence/absence dichotomous variable with "1" representing a patient that had an "O74" diagnoses across any one of the "DIAG" columns. I have attempted:

```html
do repeat x = DIAG1 to DIAG3.
compute O74 = any(x,"O74001", "O74019").
end repeat.
EXECUTE.
```

However, upon running syntax, only incidence of the above two listed codes in DIAG3 appear. Given my incredibly poor syntax skills, I cannot understand as to why incidence of O74001 and O74019 in DIAG1 and DIAG2 are not incorporated in variable "O74" when using the above "do repeat" code.

Ideally I would simply like to include "O74" in "do repeat" or a "loop" instead of typing each individual ICD code.  The syntax:

```html
compute flag = char.index(UPPER(DIAG2), 'O74') > 0.​
```

does work wonderfully, however, as coded it simply works one "DIAG" column at a time.  Given the incredibly large number of patients (>3,000,000) and number of diagnoses per patient (25), incorporating this into a loop would be ideal.  Multiple attempts have been made.

For the purposes of the "test" dataset the variables "DIAG" have been listed consecutively.  In the actual dataset, each "DIAG" is separated by two variables.  If the solution is much simpler to have these variables listed consecutively, that can certainly be done.

I greatly appreciate any input/guidance into what is likely a very elementary syntax question in SPSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason your loop doesn't work is that each time it runs the comparison for "DIAG(X)" replaces the previous comparison, so only the last one "survives".
There are many ways to correct the problem, here is the simplest:

```
compute O74=0.
do repeat x = DIAG1 to DIAG3.
if O74=0 O74 = any(x,"O74001", "O74019").
end repeat.
```

This way if O74 becomes 1 at some point it won't go back to 0 again in the next runs of the loop.
The same goes for your other syntax:

```
compute flag = 0.
do repeat x = DIAG1 to DIAG25.
if flag=0 flag = (char.index(UPPER(x), 'O74') > 0​ ).
end repeat.
```

As for the order of the DIAG variables - if they are not consecutive you just have to name them each individually (`do repeat x = DIAG1 DIAG2 DIAG3 DIAG4 ....DIAG25`). Alternatively you can use the following command to create the list in a macro (you can see an example in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913419/spss-syntax-to-add-up-values-for-all-variables-with-the-same-prefix/47914233#47914233)):

```
spssinc select variables macroname="!alldiags" /properties pattern="DIAG*".
```

After running that you can use the macro that was created like this:

```
do repeat x = !alldiags.
```

Note that any other variables beginning with "DIAG" will be captured in the list. If you do have any, look up `spssinc select variables` to try and find a way around them (or start a new question!).

Comment: Wonderful! Syntax works great!  Thank you for your very timely response